# Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking over Squarespace website

Tags: e-commerce, tracking, squarespace

I want to track Commerce data in google analytics. I have added GA code in SquareSpace as per instruction. All the website data in showing in Google Analytics data in not there. I have tried to fix the issue but I am not able to find the issue.

I am using Google site tag for GA tracking. Here is the tracking code. If anyone face same issue than please let me know how to solve this. Screenshot of tracking code:

http://prntscr.com/m91zm7

Comment: Posting screenshot of code doesn't help. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If I click on that link I get a CloudFlare image challenge. We need code examples to be in the question anyway, **in text format**. Would you edit your post?